# How can I parse 自己做 inside 自己的事情自己做? Seems no passive voice is used in it

Tags: grammar, word-order

> 自己的事情自己做 (Do one's own things by oneself)

I've analyzed above Chinese sentence as follows using direct translation.

Oneself's matter must **be done by oneself**

But there seems no passive voice structure in the initially given sentence, so my bold sentence is wrong, but as I read from left to right straightforward, **oneself do** can only be seen.

What grammatical knowledge am I missing?

Comment: I noticed that I missed inserting 要 between 自己的事情 and 自己做.
But the website I found on internet omitted it somehow...

Comment: I've been still not accustomed to Chinese grammar so I think I've thrown my post with a trivial reason,so I'm sorry Tang Ho..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己的事情自己做 is a [topic + comment] sentence, the straight translation is

Topic: 自己的事情 = one's own thing,

Comment: 自己做 = (one must) do it oneself

Translators often use the passive voice when it sounds more natural than using the active voice

自己的事情自己做 can be translated as either sentence below

- "one's own thing, (*must be*) done by oneself" -- passive voice
- "one's own thing, (one *must*) do it oneself" -- active voice

*"do it myself" is not a passive voice, myself is still the subject*